# MongoJS - No Error On Unique Index

Tags: mongodb, mongojs

So I'm messing around with MongoDB using MongoJS and can't seem to get an error to be returned when a unique ID exists.

So this is the code I am using:

```
server.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
  var details = req.params;

  details.password = md5(details.password).toString();

  db.users.insert(details,
    function (err, test1, test2) {
      console.log(err);
  });

});
```

So I hit /register with username=username&password=password and initially it will add it to the database. If I then visit the same URL again, I don't get any errors that there is already an entry with that username even though I have the following set in MongoLab:

```
{
  "v": 1,
  "unique": true,
  "key": {
    "username": 1
  },
  "name": "username",
  "ns": "restapi.users",
  "background": true
}
```

What do I need to do to get the 'err' to return the correct error code for duplicate entry? I believe it should return 11000.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a "buggy" response from mongojs which likely results from it's implementation of returning the "inserted" object as a response. The "core" driver does not do this but would either return a "ok" response or an error:

```js
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err,db) {

    var collection = db.collection('users');

    collection.insert({ "username": 2 },function(err,res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log( res );
    });

  });
```

So it seems that `mongojs` "mucks this up" while attempting this change in the API behaviour. Consequently, the errors from [Bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations are also not properly reported. But at least you can get a response that tells you for sure that nothing is actually inserted:

```js
var mongojs = require('mongojs'),
    db = mongojs('test');


var collection = db.collection('users')

var bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

bulk.insert({ "username": 2 });
bulk.execute(function(err,res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log( res );
});
```

If the username exists then the response would be:

```js
{ writeErrors: [],
  writeConcernErrors: [],
  nInserted: 0,
  nUpserted: 0,
  nMatched: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  nRemoved: 0,
  upserted: [],
  ok: 1 }
```

If it's a new "unique" value then the response would be:

```js
{ writeErrors: [],
  writeConcernErrors: [],
  nInserted: 1,
  nUpserted: 0,
  nMatched: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  nRemoved: 0,
  upserted: [],
  ok: 1 }
```

If you wanted the `_id` of a new document at least, I would have said to use ["upserts"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.upsert) with Bulk operations, but the implementation there is broken as well. In fact the "wrapping" methods still done by `monjojs` do not include any option to use "upserts" at all.

So the final thing you can do is use the [`.runCommand()`](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#database-commands) method from the `db` object and process the "upsert" that way:

```js
var mongojs = require('mongojs'),
    db = mongojs('test');

db.runCommand(
  {
    "update": "users",
    "updates": [
      {
        "q": { "username": 4 },
        "u": { "$setOnInsert": { "username": 4 } },
        "upsert": true
      }
    ],
    "ordered": true
  },
  function(err,res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log( res );
  }
);
```

It still does not report the error for the duplicate key ( upserts won't do that ) but the response at least tells you the relevant information. On "upsert" it will report this:

```js
{ ok: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  n: 1,
  upserted: [ { index: 0, _id: 5580da465e2076d9ea0c5885 } ] }
```

And where the value is found and the data is therefore not modified due to [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) then the response would be:

```js
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }
```

So if you are going to still work with `mongojs` then you need to accept the limitations and work around them as demonstrated.